# Remove Visual White Space Between HTML Elements

Tags: html, css

I am very new to HTML and I need some help on removing visual white space in my HTML code when I compile run it.

This is what I want my HTML page to look like in this specific area:

[image]

And this is how it looks on my end (I don't want this. I want it to look like the image above)

[image]

This is the code I am using for the table element:

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <p>Gorras</p>
    <ol>
        <li>Small - $10.00</li>
        <li>Medium - $12.00</li>
        <li>Large - $15.00</li>
</ol>        
</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>
    <p>Camisas</p>
    <ol>
        <li>Small - $20.00</li>
        <li>Medium - $22.00</li>
        <li>Large - $25.00</li>
</ol>        
</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>
    <p>Calzado</p>
    <ol>
        <li>Small - $50.00</li>
        <li>Medium - $60.00</li>
        <li>Large - $75.00</li>
</ol>        
</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>
    <p>Gafas</p>
    <ol>
        <li>Small - $10.00</li>
        <li>Medium - $12.00</li>
        <li>Large - $15.00</li>
</ol>        
</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way I can remove these spaces between each list?

Thank you very much and please forgive me because I am new to HTML.

Comment: Try - `ul, li, p {margin:0px;}` http://jsfiddle.net/4fzL07qf/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<p></p>` tag and add `margin` style as below

```
<ul  style="margin:0;">
    <li>
    Gorras
    <ol>
        <li>Small - $10.00</li>
        <li>Medium - $12.00</li>
        <li>Large - $15.00</li>
</ol>        
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am afraid, removing `p` tag is not a solution to this

Comment: As he is very new to HTML , I provide an easy solution for him, that's all. He'll learn deeper in future , i hope, and avoid this.

Comment: @MichaelOrtiz the answer provided by Mr Alien is a widely used solution. I recommend using the reset found below http://stackoverflow.com/a/25535189/1342440

Comment: Yes, you can keep <p></p> tag as <p style="margin:0"></p> . I removed that for simplicity.

Comment: Generally don't use inline styling, it's a bad practice. You should always use external css file.

Answer (score 2):

Just put `margin:0` on your `p`  and `ul` elements

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f0wzx12k/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the user agent stylesheet, for a quick fix, you can use

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kefdj5od/)

So here, the `*` means reset the `margin` and `padding` of ALL elements in the document and then accordingly you can provide `margin-left` to your lists like

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul {
    margin-left: 50px;
}

ol {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

We reset the `margin` and `padding` because say browsers like Firefox, Chrome, etc apply some base styles to your HTML document which is also known as User Agent Stylesheet so inorder to have minimal cross browser issues you should use [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or using `*` selector with `margin` and `padding` would suffice as well.

But if you see, am using too general selectors here, so it is better to assign a `class` to your elements or you can wrap them under a single `div` and assign a `class` to that and select your lists appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the margin

```
ul, li, p {margin: 0;}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f0wzx12k/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

That is because of the default margin on `<ul>`. This margin is from the default set of styles the browser uses when no style is specified.

You can find that using the developer console of any modern browser (developer console can be got from hitting `F12`).

This is what Chrome shows, and you can see the margins taking the space. (Click the "Select an Element" option - the little magnifying glass on the top left corner of the developer tools window. This is a pointer icon on IE, and then click on the element that you want to "Inspect".)

[image]